# two lines in a button text with different sizes

Tags: android

I found reference by googling that led me to think the following would give me 2 lines of text in a button, first line normal size and second line smaller.   However it just wraps all the copy and in the same size.   any suggestions please?  This is the line in my strings.xml

```
<string name="teststr"> String I am testing\n <small><small>(with a sub comment)</small></small></string>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use

```
myButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("String I am testing<br/><small>(with a sub comment)</small>"));
```

or to read the string from your strings.xml

```
myButton.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.teststr)));
```

Remember that you need to use <br/> instead of \n to get a new line.

Comment: is it possible with spannable?

Comment: this sollution is not working. what could be the prob?

Answer (score 11):

You can solve it by setting the string recource similar to what you suggested in your question:

For example

```
<string name="button_text"><font size="20">First line!</font>\n\<font size="10">Second line!</font></string>
```

The  will change the size of the text and the \n\ will put the following text on the next line.

Then in your XML you as usual call

```
android:text="@string/button_text"
```

Hope this will help furure readers

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. I solved using spannable string

Answer (score 3):

Button allow multiple text but issue is with Spannable String.

XML Attributes
, Spannable String
, From HTML

None of them able to tweak font sizes.

Instead of Button use custom layout with TextViews. TextView.SetText supports all of these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe buttons will only allow a single line of text. But you can easily achieve this by creating a custom view or viewgroup and add the 2 lines of text as you wish. As the onclicklistener can be added to any view, it can be used as a button.

Answer (score -4):

You can have multiple lines of text on a Button